# TensorFlow while loop with condition dependent on body

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop

I want to have a while loop with the condition dependent on a tensor computed in the loop body, but I don't know how to accomplish this with [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop).

My input processing includes random cropping, but some crops can lead to low-quality examples and I want to discard those and try a new random crop until an example of sufficient quality is obtained. The inputs are cropped by

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
IMAGE_SHAPE = [960, 720]
CROP_SHAPE = [320, 240]
max_begin_index = np.array(IMAGE_SHAPE) - np.array(CROP_SHAPE)
crop_begin_index = tf.round(tf.random_uniform([2]) * max_begin_index)
img_crop = tf.slice(img, crop_begin_index, crop_shape + [-1])
```

and the condition is

```
cond = tf.count_nonzero(img_crop > 0) > 0.5 * tf.size(img_crop)
```

Going over the documentation and examples of `tf.while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, ...)`, what I understand is that both `cond` and `body` should take the same arguments given in `loop_vars`.
I don't see how I can have `cond` depend on `img_crop` which would be calculated inside `body`, and isn't provided in `loop_vars`.

I could equivalently compute `cond` using `crop_begin_index` without actually cropping, but it depends on the random values computed inside the loop, so I have the same problem.

Is this indeed a limitation of TF looping? If not, how can I rewrite my code to use `tf.while_loop()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments that are passed on to the `condition` function are the arguments returned from your `body` function. So you just have to return that value that you want to base your condition on in the `body` function, then carry out the condition on that value in your `cond` function. Something like,

```
def body(image_shape, crop_shape, img_crop):
    max_begin_index = np.array(IMAGE_SHAPE) - np.array(CROP_SHAPE)
    crop_begin_index = tf.round(tf.random_uniform([2]) * max_begin_index)
    img_crop = tf.slice(img, crop_begin_index, crop_shape + [-1])
    return (image_shape, crop_shape, img_crop)

def cond(image_shape, crop_shape, img_crop):
    return tf.count_nonzero(img_crop > 0) > 0.5 * tf.size(img_crop)

image_shape, crop_shape, img_crop = tf.while_loop(cond=cond, body=body, loop_vars=([960, 720], [320, 240], img_crop))
```

Don't have access to an interpreter right now, so there might be some syntax problems there, but something like that.

Also, if I recall correctly, the body and the condition need to be pure functions, you cannot alter the outer state from within the functions.

Also note, you'll need to specify some initial value for `img_crop` in the loop vars.

Moreover, by default, `tf.while_loop` expects the shapes of all the `loop_vars` to remain the same across all loop runs. You can modify this through the `shape_invariants` argument.

Comment: Got it. I was also able to use just `crop_begin_index` as a variable like I wrote so the loop is more concise. Thanks!